# Examples of non linear partial order relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, order-theory

Apart from $\subseteq$, what are examples of nonlinear partial order relations?

Comment: What do you mean by nonlinear? $a < b$ not implying that $a + c <  b + c$?

Comment: Linear order is the same thing as total order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $\mathbb N$, consider that relation $a\mid b$, for instance.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Take a $T_0$ space $X$ (not $T_1$, to avoid boring cases) and define $x \le y$ iff $x \in \overline{\{y\}}$, for $x,y \in X$.